# Implement pwinty API using Java library

Tags: java, git

I'm trying to get to grips with using pwinty with a site i'm developing and seem to be in way over my head. The library file I (think I) need is: https://github.com/OddPrints/pwinty-java-sdk. I can't seem to find any proper clues on how to go about incorporating this.

Do I need to somehow package the zip into another format? If so, how?
Do I link this to my html using a  tag? What then?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the author did not publish compiled jars to a central repository like JCenter or maven central.

In order to use it you will have to clone and build the jars from sources.

Should be simple, however, the build needed some tweaks to make it work.

See following steps:

1. `git clone https://github.com/OddPrints/pwinty-java-sdk.git`
2. Edit build.gradle in the newly cloned repo:
   https://gist.github.com/galusben/967319bdff5ae6fb0bbc64081a547c47
3. run './gradlew build -x test'
4. Make sure you find the sdk jars in your m2: '~/.m2/repository/uk/co/mattburns/pwinty/pwinty-java-sdk/2.3.1'
5. In your project, if you are using maven simply add the dependency. If you are using gradle you will have to add mavenLocal() to your repositories and add `apply plugin: 'maven'` gradle example: https://gist.github.com/galusben/e0f71f90da3488ebacc0a46c7412d8fa
   Otherwise, just add the jars to your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - will try this asap!